# Why won't image directory save in MYSQL

Tags: php

The script seems to upload images to a folder, that works. But it is supposed to upload images to the row where the session name is matched.

Instead i am returned the value of '0'. I have no idea why? Is it something to do with my query?

```
      <? 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

  $name = $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); 
   if (!$name) {
    echo "Boo!";
}
 if ($_POST['submit']) {
    //get file attributes

    $Name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

    if ($Name) {            
    $location = "avatars/$Name";    
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location ) or die('Failed to upload picture');
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE fgusers3 SET imagelocation='$location' WHERE name='$name'");      die("Your profile image has been uploaded!");
    if (!$query) {
        die("Did not upload correctly");
    }
        }}



 error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);


echo "Upload your image below:
  <form action='profilepic.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   Profile Picture: <input type='file' name='myfile'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='upload'>
   </form>
";

    ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i am returned the value 0"? Also, at the end of the line where you set $query, there is a semi-colon BEFORE you call `die()`. It means that the `die()` function will be called whatever `mysql_query()` returns. It also means that the `if()` function below that line will never be executed.

Comment: All your query is placing in to the database is location string `avatars/$Name`, not the binary data (which is typically a bad idea to store in a SQL database anyway) for the image.  Where are you getting 0 returned?

Comment: Stop using this code NOW. You are opening your server to a total remote compromise by allowing ANY kind of file to be uploaded ANYWHERE on your server. You are also wide open to SQL injection attacks. Until you learn how to securely handle uploads, STOP.

Comment: i am getting it returned in my record 'imagelocation'

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com)